# How to make an executable jar?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm creating a new web application using Maven. I have got some code from 'spring's guides online which creates a database. However for some reason, the code is never being ran.

In my pom.xml, I have included the following code:

```
   <properties>
    <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>    
   </properties>
```

And this is the 'Application' class which I got from the spring guides.

`package hello;`

```
 import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Application {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // simple DS for test (not for production!)
    SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(org.h2.Driver.class);
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem");
    dataSource.setPassword("");

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    System.out.println("Creating tables");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("drop table customers if exists");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("create table customers(" +
            "id serial, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255))");

    String[] names = "John Woo;Jeff Dean;Josh Bloch;Josh Long".split(";");
    for (String fullname : names) {
        String[] name = fullname.split(" ");
        System.out.printf("Inserting customer record for %s %s\n", name[0], name[1]);
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "INSERT INTO customers(first_name,last_name) values(?,?)",
                name[0], name[1]);
    }

    System.out.println("Querying for customer records where first_name = 'Josh':");
    List<Customer> results = jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select * from customers where first_name = ?", new Object[] { "Josh" },
            new RowMapper<Customer>() {
                @Override
                public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    return new Customer(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("first_name"),
                            rs.getString("last_name"));
                }
            });

    for (Customer customer : results) {
        System.out.println(customer);
    }
}
```

}

My Project structure is as follows:

Project name

- src

  - webapp

    - hello

      - application.java

I am pretty new to this but I just can't see why its not finding the application.java file.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is the whole pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org       
/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>embed.tomcat.here</groupId>
 <artifactId>EmbedTomcatNew</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>EmbedTomcatNew Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <properties>
    <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>    
</properties>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
   <finalName>EmbedTomcatNew</finalName>
   <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>          
          <configuration>   
            <port>9966</port>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>

   </build>

  </project>
```

EDIT:
I should also mention that it is running a jsp file - which only has 'hello world' in it that prints to the browser - so it is running but I want it to run the java class first.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code is not what we need to see, we need to see more of your `pom.xml` and the way you are trying to execute your application (are you creating a runnable jar?) etc.

Comment: `matt` Edit your post and put a proper title that reflects the subject of the code/problem and not "Why doesn't it work?" otherwise we will have 2^64 post with those kind of topic.

Comment: Sorry, it has been edited now. I am using an embedded version of tomcat so that it can be run on any machine just by running the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

### WAR

You are building a `.war` file, as evidenced in the `<packaging>war</packaging>` definition, which is only deployable to a Web Application container. There is no startup class, and as well documented on stackoverflow there is do way to control the order of startup in most web app containers.

### JAR

You have to change your project to be an executable `.jar` and specify the `main` class in the `Manifest` in the `jar plugin` configuration options. Just setting some random property isn't going to do anything.

You probably want to use the `shade` plugin to bundle all the transient dependencies into a monolithic `.jar` as well otherwise you have an `classpath` installation nightmare on your hands.

Here is an example, running this from the `src/main/webapp` dir is a bad non-portable idea, that should be passed in as an argument.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        //The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
        //Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

        tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks - the thing is I need to able to run this on any machine - so I put the embedded tomcat in. I just tried to run the project after making the changes and nothing appeared to run after it had compiled. Can I still use this embedded tomcat now the packaging is set as Jar?

Comment: Make a multi-module project; one module makes the war, another makes the launcher. Use the maven-appassembler-plugin for that.

Comment: Read my answer completely, you have to follow all the steps and understand how to start an `executable jar file` the details are way to broad and out of scope for stackoverflow. It is well documented and easily found via google and a little bit of effort.

Comment: I have read it - I have now executed a jar and the database has been created - however now the tomcat server hasnt been started. Believe me I have spent the last few days on google!

Comment: you have to start the tomcat server in your code, it is pretty clear in the embedded tomcat instructions